# How do I rename a package in Lerna?

Tags: javascript, lerna

Can I simply rename the folder? I don't see any specific command in the [manual](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#readme).

Current folder structure:

```
/
|
+-- package.json
+-- lerna.json
+-- packages/
    |
    +-- dep1
    +-- dep2
    +-- app
```

Root `package.json` contents:

```
{
  "name": "splitting",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lerna": "^3.20.2"
  }
}
```

Root `lerna.json` contents:

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

File `package.json` in `packages/app/` contents:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "dep1": "^0.0.1",
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Give the package a new name inside the relevant package.json? May you share a simple representation of the folder structure?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I don't know, I don't want to mess the Lerna setup as I don't fully understand yet how it manages local dependencies. I've added folder structure and other details to the question.

Comment: The individual package.json is not the lerna setup. That's the lerna.json...

Comment: I don't get it... I added both the Lerna configuration JSON plus one of the packages `package.json` portion, to show that the the latter depends on another local package. I meant that I don't know if by simply renaming things around I can break how Lerna handles my packages.

Comment: Lerna only knows the name of a package because it says so in the the relevant package.json. If you want to rename `dep1` to `depA` you need to do so in the `dep1/package.json`